# Giving each of my not-logged-in users a unique session-id in cookies

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

I need something like a session-id. I will need to track a couple of thousand users visiting a website. For load-balancing (multiple instances of PHP and NGINX) I will unfortunately not be able to use session_start() and capture the sessionid because it needs to span across multiple webservers.

These users are not logged in, so I will not know anything about them, except for their browser, ip and plugins.

I was thinking maybe using APC, and do something like 
apc_store('count', 1);

And give the current user the id = 1.

The next user will get apc_fetch('count')+1, but I think that will be very slow, and probably also contain race-conditions.

Comment: APC user cache won't work across servers, however, you could use memcache as back-end for PHP's build-in session stuff, as Pascal Martin suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the problem of *"multiple servers"* with sessions, you could store your sessions in something else than the file system.

For example, you could :

- Store sessions in a database, shared by all webservers
- Or store sessions in a memcached cluster *(better solution -- and pretty easy)*

A couple of interesting links :

- To specify your own session handler : [`session_set_save_handler()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)
- [Enhance PHP session management](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/enhance_php_session_management/)
- [Storing your PHP sessions using memcached](http://www.dotdeb.org/2008/08/25/storing-your-php-sessions-using-memcached/)

Comment: I actually just want to set a unique cookie on a client, I am not using their actual session to anything. Would it be a waste to setup memcached up for this?

Comment: Oh, if you don't want to store anything in the session, and only generate a random identifier that you'll store in a cookie... why not just use uniqid() ?